# Why does the RequestDispatcher encode the client request uri by attaching it to the static resource path?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I got An unexpected result  while doing a mapping that returned a static resource matching a user request.

Below is an example controller.

```
@Controller
public class StaticController {
    @GetMapping("/path")
    public String getStaticOnePath() {
        return "index.html";
    }
    @GetMapping("/path/two")
    public String getStaticTwoPath() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

And This is my project directory structure.

```
main
+- java
+- resources
  +- static
    +- index.html
```

When requested with a uri of "/path", "index.html" was successfully returned.
But When requested with a uri of "/path/two", occured a 404 NOT FOUND error.

What I found out while analyzing the reason is that the `getRequestDispatcher()` method of the Request class, which is an implementation of HttpServletRequest, performed the following operation.

```
if (path.startsWith("/")) {
    return context.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path);
}

...

if (context.getDispatchersUseEncodedPaths()) {
    if (pos >= 0) {
        relative = URLEncoder.DEFAULT.encode(requestPath.substring(0, pos + 1),                                     StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + path;
    } else {
        relative = URLEncoder.DEFAULT.encode(requestPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + path;
    }
}
```

As a result of this action, a relative path of /path/index.html was returned, and I did not expect this result at all.

The problem is solved by declaring the path of the return file to start with "/" like "/index.html".
However, the results of previous performance are still difficult to predict or understand.

Can you tell me why the above is done in the process of creating a relative path?

The problem is solved by declaring the path of the return file to start with "/" like "/index.html".